# Permissions to create a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Under GKE (account created by my boss) I should be granted permissions to be able to create a Kubernetes cluster from Gcloud console, as shown in this picture:

[image]

I was granted these permissions: `Kubernetes Engine Admin` and `Service Account User`

But when trying to create the cluster I get this error:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions on which permissions I need to be granted, please?

Comment: Can you try creating a cluster using the gcloud command line? Open the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quickstart) then create a basic cluster using the following: 'gcloud container clusters create my-cluster --zone [your-zone] --verbosity debug'. This will tell you exactly which permission is missing. With Kubernetes Engine Admin you should have the correct permissions for this, so this might be a bug

Comment: Looks like a bug in the UI. I'll report it.

Comment: `Kubernetes Engine Admin` should be enough permissions to create a Kubernetes cluster, I'd recommend trying gcloud as well to see if that also gives a permission error. The bug you see in the UI might be something other than permissions.

Comment: I asked to be granted with "Kubernetes Engine API" and those error disappear. Now I can operate correctly.